# Getting rid of unchecked cast in reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am loading a class using classloader which returns me `Class<?>` and now I want to pass the class to another method or function that takes `Class<? extends SomeClass>`.

Now when I try to cast:

```
Class<?> clazzFromClassLoader = Class.forName(nameOfClass);
Class<? extends Someclass> clazz = (Class<? extends SomeClass>)clazzFromClassLoader;
//second line gives unchecked cast warning
```

I can make sure that there is no class cast exception by using

```
SomeClass.isAssignableFrom(clazzFromClassLoader);
```

But is there a way to get rid of unchecked cast?

Comment: Yes I can do that. Generics gave something but took away something too

Comment: This link - http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ006 might be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes: you can write:

```
Class<? extends Someclass> clazz =
    clazzFromClassLoader.asSubclass(Someclass.class);
```

(See [`asSubclass`'s Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29) for more information.)

Comment: Ohh Bummer I tried the but in inverse manner. Thanks. I got it.